# Tkinter Label Won't fit in the window after creating an executable with pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, label, pyinstaller

I made an application with the pyinstaller, but on some machines that will use it, cutting out some labels from the window, in addition two textbox, [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlN9W.png). How can I solve this?
In my machine it fits, in another don't.
I think the problem is the place() method, but I don't know why it works in a computer and don't in another.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter.messagebox

class Application(ttk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        ttk.Style(main_window)
        font.nametofont("TkTextFont").configure(size=12)
        font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont").configure(size=12)
        #Cabecalho
        ttk.Label(self, text="Requisições", font='arial 18 bold').place(x=150, y=5)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Desligamento", font='arial  18 bold').place(x=142, y=35)
        #Informações usúario
        ttk.Label(self, text="Usuário", font='arial  16 bold').place(x=10, y=100)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Email:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=128)
        ttk.Entry(self, width=20).place(x=85, y=128)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Senha:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=158)
        ttk.Entry(self,  show="•").place(x=85, y=158)
        #Lote
        ttk.Label(self, text="Lote", font='arial 16 bold').place(x=10, y=190)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Início:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=220)
        ttk.Entry(self, width=10).place(x=85, y=220)
        ttk.Label(self, text="Final:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=248)
        ttk.Entry(self, width=10).place(x=85, y=250)
        ttk.Label(self,text="dd/mm/aaaa",foreground='red',font='arial 10 italic').place(x=93, y=280)
        ttk.Button(self,text= 'Download').place(x=210, y=215)
        ttk.Button(self,text= 'Planilha').place(x=210, y=247)
        #Informações
        ttk.Label(self, text="Informações",font='arial 16 bold').place(x=10, y=310)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Anexado").place(x=160, y=305)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Pendente").place(x=280, y=305)
        #Montagem listbox
        frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
        frame.pack()
        frame.place(x=10,y=340)
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(frame,width=45, height=8, selectbackground='#808080', selectmode= 'extended')
        self.listbox.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Exibir").place(x=10, y=525)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Aprovada").place(x=160, y=525)
        ttk.Button(self, text="E mail Ponto").place(x=310, y=525)
        ttk.Button(self, text="E mail Pendente", ).place(x=10, y=560)
        # Informações da carta a ser exibida
        ttk.Label(self,text="Requisição:"      , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=10)       
        ttk.Label(self,text="Nome:"            , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=40)             
        ttk.Label(self,text="Aviso Prévio:"    , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1000, y=40)        
        ttk.Label(self,text="Motivo:"          , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=650 , y=10)           
        ttk.Label(self,text="Comunicação:"     , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1010, y=10)     
        ttk.Label(self,text="Desligamento:"    , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1300, y=10)    
        ttk.Label(self,text="Matrícula:"       , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1310, y=40)       
        ttk.Label(self,text="Salário:"         , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=70)          
        ttk.Label(self,text="Admissão:"        , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=650 , y=70)         
        ttk.Label(self,text="Atualização:"     , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=910, y=70)
        ttk.Label(self,text="Cargo:"           , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1160, y=70)
        #Montagem Janela Observação
        ttk.Label(self,text="Observações", font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1210, y=100)
        self.obs = tk.Text(self,height=10, width=42, fg="black", bg="white", font=("arial ", 12))
        self.obs.place(x=1210, y=130)
        #Montagem caixa de texto
        ttk.Label(self, text="Carta Inconsistente", font='arial  14 bold').place(x=10, y=600)
        self.texto = tk.Text(self, height=9, width=45, fg="#0911D0", bg="white", font=("arial ", 12), cursor="pencil")
        self.texto.place(x=10, y=630)
        # Botão Enviar email para carta náo ok
        ttk.Button(self, text="Enviar E mail").place(x=10, y=800)
        # Botão Sair
       ttk.Button(self, text="Sair", command=self.quit).place(x=310, y=800)
def main():
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    main_window.title("Desligamentos")
    main_window.state("zoomed")
    app = Application(main_window)
    app.mainloop()  
if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, Where is your code?

Comment: I bet you are either using `place`, or forcing the window to a specific size. Tkinter excels at laying out windows so that everything fits (if possible), but only if you take advantage of the features that do so.

Comment: Hi Fares, I'm new here, I can't send my code here.

Comment: Bryan, I've used .place() in all my code.

Comment: @LucasPeixoto, you can edit the question and paste your code, but make sure you use the proper format `(i.e. Ctrl + k , then paste)`.

Comment: @FaresSalem done

Comment: I don't think this problem is related to pyinstaller, it's solely the code itself, or does it?

Comment: @FaresSalem This problem happens only in some machines, in another the window opens without cutting

Comment: @LucasPeixoto That still doesn't mean that the problem is with pyinstaller.

Comment: This link might be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61433719/tkinter-label-wont-fit-in-the-window-after-creating-an-executable-with-pyinstal?r=SearchResults&s=65|0.0000

Comment: @LucasPeixoto The problem is with place. Place is not the best geometry manager. I would suggest you create your own geometry manager, or if you don't want to do that, you'll have to use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a suggestion, add a new parameter to `.place()` called `anchor`. Anchor determines what part of the widget goes to the coordinate specified. For example, if `anchor = "center"`, and the coordinates specified with relx and rely are 0.5 and 0.5 relatively, then the middle of the widget will go to 0.5, 0.5.

Sometimes the anchor is nw, or top left, and sometimes the widget goes to the side of the screen.

So, set your `anchor` to "center", and tell me what happens.

Hopefully this helps!

EDIT:

This would be your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
import tkinter.messagebox

class Application(ttk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        self.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Style(main_window)
        font.nametofont("TkTextFont").configure(size=12)
        font.nametofont("TkDefaultFont").configure(size=12)
        #Cabecalho
        ttk.Label(self, text="Requisições", font='arial 18 bold').place(x=150, y=5, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self, text="Desligamento", font='arial  18 bold').place(x=142, y=35, anchor = "center")
        #Informações usúario
        ttk.Label(self, text="Usuário", font='arial  16 bold').place(x=10, y=100, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self, text="Email:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=128)
        ttk.Entry(self, width=20).place(x=85, y=128, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self, text="Senha:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=158, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Entry(self,  show="•").place(x=85, y=158, anchor = "center")
        #Lote
        ttk.Label(self, text="Lote", font='arial 16 bold').place(x=10, y=190, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self, text="Início:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=22, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Entry(self, width=10).place(x=85, y=220, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self, text="Final:", font='arial  14').place(x=10, y=248, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Entry(self, width=10).place(x=85, y=250, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self,text="dd/mm/aaaa",foreground='red',font='arial 10 italic').place(x=93, y=280, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self,text= 'Download').place(x=210, y=215, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self,text= 'Planilha').place(x=210, y=247, anchor = "center")
        #Informações
        ttk.Label(self, text="Informações",font='arial 16 bold').place(x=10, y=310, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self, text="Anexado").place(x=160, y=305, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self, text="Pendente").place(x=280, y=305, anchor = "center")
        #Montagem listbox
        frame = tk.Frame(main_window)
        frame.pack()
        frame.place(x=10,y=340, anchor = "center")
        self.listbox = tk.Listbox(frame,width=45, height=8, selectbackground='#808080', selectmode= 'extended')
        self.listbox.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical")
        self.scrollbar.config(command=self.listbox.yview)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.listbox.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        ttk.Button(self, text="Exibir").place(x=10, y=525, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self, text="Aprovada").place(x=160, y=525, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self, text="E mail Ponto").place(x=310, y=525, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Button(self, text="E mail Pendente", ).place(x=10, y=560, anchor = "center")
        # Informações da carta a ser exibida
        ttk.Label(self,text="Requisição:"      , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=10, anchor = "center")       
        ttk.Label(self,text="Nome:"            , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=40, anchor = "center")             
        ttk.Label(self,text="Aviso Prévio:"    , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1000, y=40, anchor = "center")        
        ttk.Label(self,text="Motivo:"          , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=650 , y=10, anchor = "center")           
        ttk.Label(self,text="Comunicação:"     , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1010, y=10, anchor = "center")     
        ttk.Label(self,text="Desligamento:"    , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1300, y=10, anchor = "center")    
        ttk.Label(self,text="Matrícula:"       , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1310, y=40, anchor = "center")       
        ttk.Label(self,text="Salário:"         , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=450 , y=70, anchor = "center")          
        ttk.Label(self,text="Admissão:"        , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=650 , y=70, anchor = "center")         
        ttk.Label(self,text="Atualização:"     , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=910, y=70, anchor = "center")
        ttk.Label(self,text="Cargo:"           , font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1160, y=70, anchor = "center")
        #Montagem Janela Observação
        ttk.Label(self,text="Observações", font='arial 14 bold').place(x=1210, y=100, anchor = "center")
        self.obs = tk.Text(self,height=10, width=42, fg="black", bg="white", font=("arial ", 12))
        self.obs.place(x=1210, y=130, anchor = "center")
        #Montagem caixa de texto
        ttk.Label(self, text="Carta Inconsistente", font='arial  14 bold').place(x=10, y=600, anchor = "center")
        self.texto = tk.Text(self, height=9, width=45, fg="#0911D0", bg="white", font=("arial ", 12), cursor="pencil")
        self.texto.place(x=10, y=630, anchor = "center")
        # Botão Enviar email para carta náo ok
        ttk.Button(self, text="Enviar E mail").place(x=10, y=800, anchor = "center")
        # Botão Sair
        ttk.Button(self, text="Sair", command=self.quit).place(x=310, y=800, anchor = "center")
def main():
    main_window = tk.Tk()
    main_window.title("Desligamentos")

    app = Application(main_window)
    app.mainloop()  
if __name__=="__main__":
        main()
```

Please tell me if this works!!

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work, keep in mind that ```.place()``` isn't the best geometry manager. I ran this program on my monitor, and everything fit on the screen. When I ran it on my computer normally, though, some elements were cut off. It depends on what size screen you use. Hopefully, this clears some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider something like this, fixing the GUI size `top.resizable(0, 0)`, and using  `relx`, `rely`, `relheight` and `relwidth` with `place()`, The values are relative to the parent widget, so if you have nested widgets (i.e a text box inside a label frame, then values for the label frame are relative to the top window and for the text box relative to the label frame).

```
try:
    from tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from Tkinter import *

try:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1
except ImportError:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0

def create_window():
    global root, top
    root = Tk()            # creating a tkinter window, Tk is a class
    top = MainFrame(root)  # building the gui, so it's like MainFrame is inheriting the Tk class
    root.mainloop()        # infinite main loop

class MainFrame:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')

        top.geometry("802x557+250+104")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(2970, 881)
        top.resizable(0, 0)      # fixing the GUI size

        self.Labelframe = LabelFrame(top)
        self.Labelframe.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4, relheight=0.279, relwidth=0.264)
        self.Labelframe.configure(text='''Test label''', background="#d9d9d9")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_window()
```

Comment: Turning off the ability to resize the window is a good way to annoy the users, and makes this problem worse rather than better since the user has lost the ability to make the window larger in order to see cut off widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley That's up to the requirements of the project I think but it's a good point, Usability is something important. 
Using `relx` etc. should be enough to solve the problem I think, try running the code with and without the fixed-size code line.

Comment: I'll try this @FaresSalem. I was thinking in change self.place(relwidth =1, relheight=1) by self.pack(expand=True, fill='both').

Comment: @LucasPeixoto I'm not sure what that will do, but I'm sure that the way I proposed will work, You should try :D

Comment: @FaresSalem your suggestion is use in every .place()  relx and rely ?

Comment: But in your case you don’t have nested widgets, so all the values are relative to the top window.

Comment: @faressalem I've changed x and y for relx and rely, and other distortion happened. Look the new image in edit.

Comment: @LucasPeixoto Update the code as well, It seems that you need to lower the `relx` value for the text box on the right. Is the python generated GUI before generating an executable the same when resizing? It should not!

Comment: @faressalem, now it works. The problem was because I set place just with x and y in a 1600x900 resolution, in a machine with 1366x768, the widgets cuts off the window. Now I've set place with relx, rely, relwidth,relheight and anchor='center'